# Data interchange between main and content script -- Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

My Mozilla Addon (coded with the Addon SDK) needs to encrypt information in a webpage form before the form submits to the webpage's servers. The encryption library I use is only accessible in `lib/main.js` and the information to be encrypted on the webpage is gathered by a content script.

My idea was to have my Addon encrypt the data with the following process:

1. When the form's submit button is clicked, the content script sends the form's data (text in a text input) to `main.js`.
2. `main.js` encrypts the data using a library, then sends the cipher text back to the content script.
3. The content script inserts the cipher text from `main.js` into the form, which then submits to the webpage's servers.

Can I perform synchronous communication between the Addon's main code and the content script such that I can encrypt the form data after the submit button is clicked, but before the form submits the data to the servers? If not, can I halt the form's submission until I have encrypted the data, then manually prompt the form to submit with my newly encrypted input?

Any help in resolving this problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think these links will help you

**"Communicating using "port"**

"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mozilla%2FAdd-ons%2FSDK%2FGuides%2Fusing_port"

**"Communicating With Other Scripts"**

"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mozilla%2FAdd-ons%2FSDK%2FGuides%2FCommunicating_With_Other_Scripts"